# How to specify JDK to start Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

In my Linux Mint laptop, Intellij Idea throws an exception on the default JDK - OpenJDK. After I install Oracle JDK and set it as priority 1, the Oracle JDK is the output of

```
java --version
```

and

```
javac --version
```

. However, Idea still throws an exception of NoClassDefFoundError for com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel. I guess that it still uses Open JDK.

How to specify JDK to start Idea?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

Comment: What's the output of `javac -version`?

Comment: @Gabriel Java 11